# Receiving pagination as a empty object using Instagram API

Tags: javascript, pagination, instagram

I'm requesting like this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            url : 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+userId+'/media/recent? client_id=ce0ad0774299436a80d77b4e8dc783b7&access_token='+instagramUserDetails.clientAccessToken+'',
     success: function(data) 
     {
        console.info(data);
     }
```

and the response is

```
Object { pagination={...}, meta={...}, data=[6]}    
meta - Object { code=200}   
pagination - Object {}
```

Two questions :-

1.I'm getting a empty object for pagination, is something wrong in my request.What should I do for this.

2.I just what to know is there way for getting the photo of particular user and for particular tag.

Example : Josh is a user and he has some #hashtags for his photos. like he has #flowers, #trees,#cats etc., Now I want Josh's particular tag - #trees.For this Im getting the user details and iterating it. I just want to know is there any direct url to fetch the details of particular user for particular tag.

Comment: If you are not getting the pagination object means that no pagination is needed as it is only returning 6 results.

Comment: To get the avatar of a user https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user-id>?access_token=<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN> and then you will have the avatar at json.data.picture_profile. I am not sure a tag has an avatar.

Comment: Thank you so much,Im receiving the pagination object.I assume that you understood for my second question is like for the user avatar hashtag,If I miss understand you sorry,but what I meant is, suppose You have an account and you posted some photos and provided hashtag in the Instagram. Now you want the particular hashtag of your own posts.Do we have any way to get directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
If there is no more photos, then pagination will be empty.

2)
Currently there is no API to filter a user's photos by hashtag, you have to manually search for hashtags.
Once you get the photos, look for the "caption" key in the JSON and search for the hashtag, you can also search in comments.text for hashtag and then display the photos